# jquery Change date format

Tags: jquery, date, date-conversion

I have a date in this format: 05-Jun-2013, I just need year and it need to be converted to just 2013, for my validation purpose.
How can I do this, please be concerned that, .getFullYear() is not working.

Comment: is it date object or just a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default getFullYear should work. Might be a possibility that you are not having the appropriate object for usage.

You follow this approach

```
var dateString = "05-Jun-2013";
var dateStringArray = dateString.split("-");

var yearValue = dateStringArray[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date('05-Jun-2013');
alert(d.getFullYear());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RDwQ/

Answer (score 0):

Try with split like

```
my_date = '05-Jun-2013'; 
var my_arr = my_date.split('-');
alert('The year is ' + my_arr[2]);
```

Here my_arr is the array and my_arr[2] will represents the year

Comment: sorry bro unfortunately i have seen that answer first. i am extremely sorry for that. plz dont mind

Answer (score 0):

Please see below.

```
var dateObj = new Date("05-Jun-2013");
dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working for me:

```
var d = '05-Jun-2013';
var nd = new Date(d);
alert(nd.getFullYear());
```

Comment: bro plz look out my problem, i already said that .getFullYear() method is not working. but thnx for response